# Array assignment error in C++, What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, while-loop, initialization

I am trying this code in CodeBlocks but the result is some random numbers!
I appreciate if you check the code and let me know what my mistake is. It should result in multipliers of 25:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){

    const int array_size = 10;
    int numbers[array_size];
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter < array_size){
        numbers[counter] = 25 * counter;
        counter++;
        cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << numbers[counter] << endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to increment `counter` *after* you print the corresponding array item.

Comment: Your code shouldn’t even compile, it’s invalid C++. At the very least you should be getting a compiler warning, which you should always pay attention to.

Comment: Not the answer, but you probably want to be using `int main()`. Even if it doesn't return anything - `main` on it's own has undefined behaviour

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks a lot! Thanks to everyone as well

Comment: @phuclv no, `array_size` is actually a constant expression and is valid here. That said, using `constexpr` would be better.

Comment: @phuclv `array_size`is `const`, therefore it's legal C++

Comment: @Jabberwocky It being `const` is *not enough*.

Comment: @user7860670 in C# the output would have been wrong too.

Comment: *"the result is some random numbers!"* -- even when the result looks random to you, it is a good idea to copy the output (as text) into your question. Sometimes there is a pattern that you just missed. For example, someone might notice that the labels for your output go from "number[1]" to "number[10]" (instead of "number[0]" to "number[9]"), which could lead to a quick diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing `counter` after setting the value of `numbers[counter]`. After that. `numbers[counter]` (with the new value of `counter`) is a new uninitialized element.

You should move the increment *after* the printing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int array_size = 10;
    int numbers[array_size];
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter < array_size){
        numbers[counter] = 25 * counter;
        cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << numbers[counter] << endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Or simply avoid using an array (in this case):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    const int array_size = 10;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter < array_size){
        std::cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << 25 * counter << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Another way is using two loops -- one for initialization and one for printing:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    const int array_size = 10;
    int numbers[array_size];
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter < array_size){
        numbers[counter] = 25 * counter;
        counter++;
    }

    counter = 0;
    while(counter < array_size){
        cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << numbers[counter] << endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting an uninitialized element of the array after incrementing of the variable `counter`.

```
    counter++;
    cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << numbers[counter] << endl;
```

The reason of the error is usage of an inappropriate loop.

Instead of the while loop it is better to use for loop.

For example

```
for ( int counter = 0; counter < array_size; counter++ ){
    numbers[counter] = 25 * counter;
    cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << numbers[counter] << endl;
}
```

Pay attention to that the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main()
```

That is you may not omit the function return type.

Answer (score 0):

change for this code

```
const int array_size = 10;
    int numbers[array_size];
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter < array_size){
        numbers[counter] = 25 * counter;
        cout << "number[" << counter << "] = " << numbers[counter] << endl;
        counter++;
    }
```